# Is this list comprehension pythonic enough?

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

Let's say I want to create a list of `ints` using Python that consists of the cubes of the numbers 1 through 10 **only** if the **cube** is evenly divisible by four.

I wrote this working line:

```
cube4 = [x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11) if (x ** 3) % 4 == 0]
```

My beef with this line of code is that it's computing the cube of x twice. Is there *more pythonic* way to write this line? Or is this as good as it'll get in a list comprehension?

---

**Edit -** My question is intended to be focused how to avoid extraneous calculation using the features and nuances of Python while still keeping code concise and readable. Though this solution could have probably been reached looking at other questions, I wanted to be sure that I knew the *best* answer to this question, not just a solution that works.

Comment: As it is, it's very pythonic and I wouldn't worry about it. You have no idea what the runtime is doing, it may well be optimizing the x^3 term already. Or, a future version of python might. Or an alternative run time, like PyPy might. It's best to follow the language's idioms and let the language designers worry about these sorts of things, unless you've profiled your code and *know* that that list comprehension is your bottle neck. If you get to that point, then you need to worry about what your runtime is doing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a generator expression:

```
cubed = (x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11))
cube4 = [c for c in cubed if c % 4 == 0]
```

This still iterates over `range()` only *once*, but now the `x ** 3` expression is calculated just the once as the generator expression is iterated over. You can combine it into one line:

```
cube4 = [c for c in (x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11)) if c % 4 == 0]
```

but keeping the generator expression on a separate line may aid in comprehension (no pun intended).

Demo:

```
>>> [c for c in (x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11)) if c % 4 == 0]
[8, 64, 216, 512, 1000]
```

Of course, mathematically speaking, for your simple example you could just use `[x ** 3 for x in range(2, 11, 2)]`, but I suspect that wasn't quite the aim of your question. :-)

Comment: I like this generator solution a lot. This is definitely the kind of revision I was looking for. I would agree with keeping the readability paramount in two lines rather than making one less readable one too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A number's cube is divisible by 4 if and only if the number is even. This is easy to see if you expand each number into its prime factors. Therefore:

```
cube4 = [x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11) if x % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Sure, but that's not the point of the question, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I love one-liners, but it's worth noting that there's another Pythonic way to produce the desired `list`.

```
cube4 = []
for x in range(1, 11):
    y = x ** 3
    if not y%4:
        cube4.append(y)
```